# how to get data from form and load php by variable in text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how to get data from form and load php by variable in text by click on button ?

My Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#GEPLeach").click(function(){
        $("#EPLeach").hide();
        $("#EPLeached").show();
        $.get("lc.php", function(data){document.getElementById("EPLeached").innerHTML=data;});
    });
});
</script>

<form id="EPLeach">
<input name="type" type="radio" value="keyword" checked>
<input name="type" type="radio" value="URL">
<input type="text" name="input">
<input id="GEPLeach" type="submit" value="Leach">
</form>
<textarea id="EPLeached" hidden></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the form values as parameters using the second argument to `$.get()`:

```
$.get("lc.php", $("#EPLeach").serialize(), function(data) {
    $("#EPLeached").html(data);
});
```

You also need to use `event.preventDefault();` in the event handler to prevent the form from being submitted normally, or change the button to `type="button"`.